# An US iPad Air 2 warranty work in Brazil?

Tags: ipad, hardware, import, warranty

Im about to go to US, and I was thinking about buying an "iPad Air 2", but Im worryed if, for some reason, Its needed to use the warranty. Could I do this in Brazil or would I need to send it back to US for that?...

...also, does the warranty work the same way for refurbished iPad Air 2? 
Will the warranty be valid in Brazil?

Answer (score 1):

Apple has fantastic warranty service. Now I can't actually speak for Brazil but I do know that they do have a very fast mail in warranty system. That should do the trick or if you have a local apple store you can bring your iPad into their. Apple warranty is worldwide.